# mysql union to not working

Tags: mysql, join, merge, union

Hi im trying to merge two tables.

I have ids that exists only in the left table and i have ids that only exists in the right table. I want to get get one table with all ids. I tried:

```
select * from temp_hours as a
    left outer join temp_orders as o on a.proj_id = o.proj_id
union
select * from temp_hours as a
    right outer join temp_orders as o on a.proj_id = o.proj_id
```

But i get the error:

```
Can't reopen table: 'a'
```

any ideas how i can do this? Server version: 5.0.51a-24+lenny4 (Debian)

Comment: Try putting both sql query in `()`. like `(query1) union (query2)`

Comment: or use different aliases in the second select.

Comment: Not sure if this helps in your situation and I realize this is very old, but perhaps this will help others as it did me. Union, by default, uses DISTINCT. If the union pulls the same information, it will automatically only show new DISTINCT information. I had to add something distinct to each select to have it appear correctly. SELECT column, 1 FROM... UNION SELECT column, 2 FROM... More here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,220906,220926#msg-220926

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the Parenthesis as suggested or change the Abbreviation...

```
select * from temp_hours as a
    left outer join temp_orders as ao on a.proj_id = ao.proj_id
union
select * from temp_hours as b
    right outer join temp_orders as bo on b.proj_id = bo.proj_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add some parenthesis around your select queries:

```
(select * from temp_hours as a
    left outer join temp_orders as o on a.proj_id = o.proj_id)
union
(select * from temp_hours as a
    right outer join temp_orders as o on a.proj_id = o.proj_id)
```

See, e.g., the examples in the [docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

Comment: Thanks, but i still get the same error. Im using temporary tables, might that be a problem?

Comment: You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query - found it

Answer (score -1):

You need parenthesis for every select

```
(select * from temp_hours as a
    left outer join temp_orders as o on a.proj_id = o.proj_id)
union
(select * from temp_hours as a
    right outer join temp_orders as o on a.proj_id = o.proj_id)
```

But, error that you get seems [temporary table limitation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html)